# Dodge Ram blower motor works intermittently

Tags: dodge, heater

I have a 2006 Dodge Ram 2500 (5.9 L Cummins diesel). I’d replaced blower motor about 3 weeks ago and all was well until it started working intermittently. Resistor looked burnt and cracked so I’d also replaced it. Motor sounded like it was trying to run as if low voltage. Now nothing. Does this model year truck have a relay in the system as well as the resistor, and if so, where is it located? There are no relays in fuse box under the hood. Or is this a problem with the switch, and how test it?

Comment: What was the cause of initial replacement? Same symptoms?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue? My 07 2500 5.9 is having the same issue. I replaced the resistor, but still no dice. I can whack on the duct under the dash a couple of times and get good air for 2-3 minutes and then it fades off to "low voltage" if you will.

Comment: You sure you didn't get a bad resistor? With some work, you should be able to jump the motor with full voltage to see if there is actually an issue there.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with an 2004 Caraven turned out to be a bad ground installed ground wire directly from Motor works fine now